# ¿Cómo funciona y para qué sirve el operador %in%?

Tags: r

en un libro me dice que la función %in%() se puede comparar con un operador de comparación. Esta función toma dos objetos como argumentos y devuelve TRUE o FALSE para cada elemento del primer objeto de acuerdo con su presencia o ausencia en el segundo objeto.

```
print(vecManip)
## [1] 10 20 30 70 60 50 40

print(vecManip2)
## [1] 10 20 30 10 50 10 40

vecManip %in% vecManip2
## [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE

vecManip2 %in% vecManip
## [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

no comprendo muy bien cómo funciona y el para qué de %in%?

Comment: el para qué de %in%? El problema es que el ejercicio carece de contexto. Imagina que uno de tus vectores contienen los nombres de los asistentes al curso de R básico y otro el de los asistentes al curso de R avanzado ¿Que personas asistieron a ambos cursos?. Este es un problema que se presenta frecuentemente en el análisis de datos y para resolverlo podemos usar el %in%. En tu ejemplo se comparan vectores relativamente pequeños, pero la comparación se hace más compleja a medida que aumenta la longitud del vector.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

lo que esta haciendo es lo siguiente:

```
compara el 10 de vecManip y lo busca en vecManip2. Esta? si. Muestro True.
compara el 20 de   ""         ""           ""            si. Muestro true
...
compara el 70 de vecManip y lo busca en vecManip2. Esta? NO. Muestro FALSE
```

Entiendo que se utiliza para poder encontrar la INTERSECCION de los elementos de un grupo. Podrias decir que vecManip2 es un SUBCONJUNTO de vecManip puesto que todos los elementos de vecManip2 estan en vecmanip

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente `%in%` es una función, pero conocida también como un operador infijo ("infix"), tal como las operaciones aritméticas `+, -, *, /` o el pipe `%>%` y muchas otras. Son funciones que reciben únicamente dos parámetros y tienen la particularidad de poder ser interpretadas en la forma `a funcion b`. Veamos que hace particularmente `%in%`:

```
getAnywhere(`%in%`)

A single object matching ‘%in%’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:base
  namespace:base
with value

function (x, table) 
match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
<bytecode: 0x000002339366ece0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Si ves bien el código, vemos que `%in%` es prácticamente un alias de `match()`, de hecho ``` help(``%in%``) ``` apunta a la ayuda de `match()`, e incluso nos confirma:

> %in% is currently defined as  "%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x,
>   table, nomatch = 0) > 0

Particularmente `match(x, table, nomatch = 0)` nos retorna los índices de los valores del vector `x` que coinciden con los valores del vector `table`, si además hacemos `match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L` lo que estamos logrando es que **`a %in% b` nos diga que elementos del vector `a` se encuentran en `b`**. El para que se usa, básicamente siempre que necesites saber que elementos de un conjunto se encuentren contenidos en otro.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta