# Comparar dos columnas de data frames diferentes en R

Tags: r, comparaciones, dataframe

Para ejemplificar mi duda, voy a usar los siguientes dataframes:

```
df1<-data.frame(id1=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",2),"c","d"))
df2<-data.frame(id2=c("a","c"))
```

Busco generar un nuevo campo `df1$comp` que tenga valores 1 si `df1$id1` está en `df2$id2` y cero (o NA) en caso contrario. Obteniendo como resultado:

```
df1
  id1 comp
1   a    1
2   a    1
3   a    1
4   b   NA
5   b   NA
6   c    1
7   d   NA
```

Mis dataframes reales tienen 3 millones de registros y 60 mil, respectivamente. De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si está bien los valores 1 y 0, me parece que lo más sencillo es:

```
df1$comp <- as.integer(df1$id1 %in% df2$id2)

  id1 comp
1   a    1
2   a    1
3   a    1
4   b    0
5   b    0
6   c    1
7   d    0
```

Usamos el operador `%in%` para ver si cada elemento de `df1$id1` se encuentra en `df1$id2`. Para más info de `%in%` ver esta pregunta: [¿Cómo funciona y el para qué sirve el operador %in%?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270327/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-y-el-para-qu%C3%A9-de-in/270408#270408).

Si quieres un `NA` en lugar del 0 podrías hacer:

```
df1$comp <- ifelse(df1$id1 %in% df2$id2, 1, NA)
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfectamente. Probé ambas soluciones.