# ¿Cómo extraer filas de un data frame usando un vector con los valores de una de las variables en R?

Tags: r

tengo un data frame en R y quiero extraer de él las filas que tienen un determinado valor en una de sus variables a partir de los valores de otro vector.

Por ejemplo, extraer del dataframe `iris` las filas con las Especies (Species) que se encuentran en otro vector `criterio <- c("setas", "virginica")`

Answer (score 0):

utilizando el operador %in% con dplyr podría ser así:

```
# Define vector con observaciones para filtrar
# En el df de "iris" no viene "setas" es "setosa" si era esa la que querías filtrar # con esto funcionaria. 

criterio <- c("setosa", "virginica")

# Con dplyr utilizando filter
iris |> 
  filter(Species%in%criterio)

o también sirve:

iris |>
filter(Species%in%c("setosa", "virginica"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el operador `%in%`, que es el equivalente en conjuntos a pertenece.

Con el ejemplo de `iris` seria:

```
criterio <- c("setas", "virginica")
iris [iris$Species %in% criterio, ]
```

Que te regresará el subconjunto de iris en el que todas las filas de `Species` sean igual a `virginica`. Supongo que el `setas` se debe al autorrector (es `setosa`), pero lo dejé que se vea que ocurre cuando no hay una equivalencia perfecta.

El operador en este caso es `[ , ]`, que hace el subconjunto. Conservará las filas en las que la prueba lógica `%in%` regrese `TRUE`. Es importante la coma posterior, ya que un data.frame es bidimensional y es necesario pasarle dos valores para hacer un subconjunto. La coma separa dos lugares, el primero para las filas y el segundo para las columnas. Cuando uno o ambos están en en vacíos regresará todos los elementos. Es un especie de comodín.

En las respuestas a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270327/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-y-para-qu%C3%A9-sirve-el-operador-in) pregunta encontrarás más detalles sobre `%in%`